# How do I re-run my Meteor publication to refresh the contents of a collection on the client?

Tags: javascript, collections, meteor

I'm creating a quiz app. I want to show a single random question, take the user's answer, show feedback, and move to another random question.

I'm using this to publish a single random question:

```
getRandomInt = function(min, max) {
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1) + min);
};

randomizedQuestion = function(rand) {
  // These variables ensure the initial path (greater or less than) is also randomized
  var greater = {$gte: rand};
  var less = {$lte: rand};
  var randomBool = !!getRandomInt(0,1);
  var randomQuestion = Questions.find({randomizer: randomBool ? greater : less }, {fields: {body: true, answers: true}, limit: 1, sort: {randomizer: 1}});

  //  If the first attempt to find a random question fails, we'll go the other direction.
  if (randomQuestion.count()) {
    return randomQuestion;
  } else {
    return Questions.find({randomizer: randomBool ? less : greater}, {fields: {body: true, answers: true}, limit: 1, sort: {randomizer: 1}});
  }
};

Meteor.publish("question", function(rand) {
  if (rand) {
    return randomizedQuestion(rand);
  }
});
```

I have a route that subscribes to that publication:

```
Router.route("/", {
  name:"quiz",
  template:"question",
  subscriptions: function() {
    this.questionSub = Meteor.subscribe("question", Math.random());
  },
  data: function() {
    return {
      question: Questions.find(),
      ready: this.questionSub.ready
      };
  }
});
```

How can I re-run the query with a new value for `Math.random()` in order to get another random question after the user answers the question?

Comment: did you try putting the code inside an autorun?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you replace `Math.random()` with a reactive variable, that will cause your subscription to be reevaluated. For simplicity I'll use a session variable in this example.

Somewhere before the route runs (at the top of the file or in a before hook), initialize the variable:

```
  Session.setDefault('randomValue', Math.random());
```

Then change your subscription to use it:

```
  Meteor.subscribe('question', Session.get('randomValue'));
```

Finally, whenever you want to restart the subscription and update your data context, change the variable again:

```
  Session.set('randomValue', Math.random());
```

Note you may want `question: Questions.findOne()` instead of `question: Questions.find()` assuming your template needs a document instead of a cursor.

Comment: Thanks! I can make this work by passing the reactive var to the subscription, but that allows users to manipulate the random value and influence which question they'll get next. Any way to get the publication to react to the reactive variable instead and do all the randomizing on the server?

Comment: It's worth noting that the publish function doesn't have to actually use it's arguments. You could see the reactive variable on the client as merely a means to force the publish function to rerun. Internally it could compute another random value and decide which question(s) the client should see.